# Как правильно использовать ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос который вставляет запись, или в случае наличия обновляет:

```
 INSERT INTO "DocWarehouse" ("Ref", "Number", "DateTime")
    VALUES
    ('0003b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-000005020000e', '102-01500000', '2018-10-01T09:00:17'
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "Ref" = VALUES("Ref");
```

Но выдает ошибку, `[2020-01-09 09:48:14] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "DUPLICATE"`

что не так в запросе?
Спасибо

Comment: У вас точно mysql? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/244289/1 it works.

Comment: Особенно интересно, почему имена полей в двойных кавычках и это не вызывает ошибки в самом начале после "into". В mysql имена колонок заключаются в обратные апострофы. Так что можно заподозрить что это либо postgresql, либо oracle. В обоих СУБД нет синтаксиса 'on duplicate key update', в них есть собственные аналоги с совершенно другим синтаксисом

Comment: Делаю INSERT INTO "DocWarehouse" (`Ref`, `Number`, `DateTime`)
VALUES
('0003b3b4-c53f-11e8-bca5-000005020000e', '102-01500000', '2018-10-01T09:00:17')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Ref` = VALUES(`Ref`); Получаю [2020-01-09 10:12:22] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"

Comment: @mike, выставить ANSI_QUOTES в sql_mode и mysql нормально начинает понимать стандартные кавычки.

Comment: а вот если не понимает апострофы - то речь гарантированно не о mysql. Проверяйте какая именно у вас СУБД.

Comment: ну там еще сообщение об ошибке больше смахивает на postgesql. У mysql они совсем бестолковые. Так что если это все таки постгрес то там используется `on conflict`

Comment: .Вы правы, не в той консоли упорно запускал, и не мог понять в чем проблема